# supervisord with haproxy, paster, and node js

Tags: haproxy, supervisord

I have to run paster serve for my app and nodejs for my real time requirements both are configured through haproxy, but here I need to run haproxy as sudo to bind port 80 and other processes as normal user, how to do it? I tried different ways, but no use.  I tried this command

command=sudo haproxy

I think this is not the ways we should do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to run supervisord as root, and configure it to run your various services under non-privileged users instead.

```
[program:paster]
# other configuration
user = wwwdaemon
```

In order for this to work, you cannot set the `user` option in the `[supervisord]` section (otherwise the daemon cannot restart your haproxy server). You therefore do want to make sure your supervisord configuration is only writeable by root so no new programs can be added to a running supervisord daemon, and you want to make sure the XML-RPC server options are well protected.

The latter means you need to review any `[unix_http_server]`, `[inet_http_server]` and `[rpcinterface:x]` sections you have configured to be properly locked down. For example, use the `chown` and `chmod` options for the [`unix_http_server`] section to limit access to the socket file to privileged users only.

Alternatively, you can run a lightweight front-end server with minimal configuration to proxy port 80 to a non-privileged port instead, and keep this minimal server out of your supervisord setup. `ngnix` is an excellent server to do this, for example, installed via the native packaging system of your server (e.g. apt-get on Debian or Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think it is probably better to keep my haproxy out of supervisord setup and only use it to manage my paster and nodjs processes, because we do not have to restart haproxy every time we restart the other servers/process it is handling.